# How to use jquery to select a select field by the selected option value

Tags: jquery

The title explains it all.  How would jquery be used to select a select field by the selected option value.  ie.  I want to select all select fields where 2 is the value of the selected option.

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector in conjunction with an [`attribute equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
​$("select option:selected[value='2']").parent()
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BJvD8/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` selector.

```
$('select:has(option[value="2"]:selected)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#SelectId option').each(function() {
  if($(this).val()==desiredValue) $(this).attr('selected','selected');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/amomek/1/edit for an example.